# Case sensitivity on spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I had a strange issue. When 'always' is written in lowercase
(Case sensitivity on spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always),
Spring Batch does not generate tables for me. However, when I wrote it in uppercase, it worked.

It's a Spring Boot 3.1 application on Windows with PostgreSQL.

Writing "ALWAYS" in uppercase works

**Solved**:
I've figured out that using @EnableBatchProcessing or/and DefaultBatchConfiguration will back off the autoconfiguration feature.
More Info: [spring-boot-3-migration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-3-migration)

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Batch does not generate tables for me.

That is a spring boot feature, not a spring batch feature. I don't recall properties are case sensitive, the following works as expected with a lower case "always":

Generate project for Spring Initializr: https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.1.6&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=batch,h2

Update `DemoApplication.java` as follows:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("hello world");
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        }, transactionManager)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Update `application.properties` with:

```
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

With that in place, the app works as expected (with `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS` as well). While this example uses H2 to quickly test case sensitivity, it should also work for PostgreSQL.